# Does @solid-primitives/resize-observer not return the client bounds?

Tags: typescript, solid-js, resize-observer

I am struggling to get `@solid-primitives/resize-observer` to work.

Although `props.containerRef.getBoundingClientRect()` is reporting the correct bounds, when I use `createResizeObserver`, both `left` and `top` appear to be `0`.

Is it an offset from the parent? Here is a fragment of my code:

```
const Flowers: Component = (props: {containerRef: HTMLDivElement}) => {
  const [bounds, setBounds] = createSignal(null);
  const [particles, setParticles] = createSignal<Particle[]>([]);

  onMount(() => {
    const elementBounds = props.containerRef && props.containerRef.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (elementBounds) {
      setBounds(elementBounds); // <--- CORRECT
      console.log('elementBounds on mount', elementBounds);
    }
  });

  onMount(() => {
    createResizeObserver(props.containerRef, (b, element, entry,) => {
      if (element === props.containerRef) {
        console.log('DOMRect on mount', b); // <--- INCORRECT appears to be window bounds
        setBounds(b);
      }
    });
  });

  //...return something or other
}
```

If it is not expected to return the client bounding box, then fine: I will calculate that separately.